# How do I report a bug against Compiz?

Tags: unity, compiz, bug-reporting

When running GUI Unit Tests with Netbeans, I usually end up in a situation where Compiz reaches 100% of CPU usage.

When that happens, Unity freezes completely, but I can connect to my computer through SSH and kill compiz (with `sudo killall -9 compiz`).

I would like this bug to be solved, but I don't know which is the best way to collect useful information about it.
Can anyone tell me what to do? Maybe starting/killing Compiz in a different way to get a stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://wiki.compiz.org/HowtoSubmitBugReports) has full details and instructions on filing a bug on Compiz. There are also links to to their Wiki and Forums pages which may be helpful to you as well. The bug tracker is also a searchable database so make sure to check if your bug has been reported. The more people are effected by a given bug the more likely it will receive attention.